# Getting extra fields from laravel api having belongstomany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have two data tables related to each other by the belongstomany relationship. And when I am fetching data from its api controllers with selecting only two column keys `['id','title']` yet it returns some extra data in the response object.

`model`code:

```
public function place(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class,'city_place')->select(array('id', 'title'));

}
```

`controller` code:

```
public function ofcity($id)
{
    $city=City::findOrFail($id);
    return new CityResource(  $city->place()->get());

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEw3P.png)

Comment: can you please put the code for `CityResource`

Comment: namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class City extends JsonResource
{
  
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}

Comment: is it just api call or are you trying to get data on blade?

Comment: I need response data to save in data base, before it was belongsto relationship and it was working fine but when I changed its relations to belongstomany with pivot table it returns some extra data :

Comment: {"data":[{"id":2,"title":"place 1","featured_image":{"id":2,"model_type":"App\\Place","model_id":2,"collection_name":"featured_image","name":"10","file_name":"10.png","mime_type":"image\/png","disk":"public" . . .

Answer (score 1):

You must indicate the name of the table in front of the fields.

model Place code:

```
protected $columns = ['places.id', 'places.title']; //all column for select

public function scopeExclude($query, $value = [])
{
    return $query->select(\array_diff($this->columns, (array) $value));
}
```

model City code:

```
public function place()
{        
     return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class,'city_place', 'city_id', 'place_id');        
}
```

controller code:

```
public function ofcity($id)
{
    $cities = City::findOrFail($id)->place()->exclude(['featured_image'])->get()->toArray();
    return response()->json(['cities' => $cities], 200);    
}
```

In exclude skip all the fields that need not to be shown.

Comment: No help still same response

Comment: What other data does it return?

Comment: {"data":[{"id":2,"title":"place 1","featured_image":{"id":2,"model_type":"App\\Place","model_id":2,"collection_name":"featured_image","name":"10","file_name":"10.png","mime_type":"image\/png","disk":"public" . . .

I have attached a screen shot with my question ,kindly check

Comment: Try as described above.

Comment: Still same response. NO luck

Comment: message Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::exclude()

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone here helping me out but none of the above solution worked..I figured it out after trying different functions and spending hours on this.

model Place code:

public function place(){

```
    return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class,'city_place','city_id','place_id')->select(array('places.id', 'places.title'));

}
```

controller code:

public function ofcity($id)
    {
$city=City::findOrFail($id);

return new CityResource(  $city->place()->get()->map(function ($item,$key) {

```
 return ['id' => $item['id'],'title'=>$item['title']];
    })

    );
```